# Migration Strategy for MySQL 5.5 to Percona 5.6

Tags: mysql, percona

I want to Upgrade an old MySQL 5.5 to Percona 5.6. Of course with as litle downtime as posible.

The new server with Percona 5.6 will be already set up. So I think about the following approach:

- Stop old MySQL 5.5
- copy data dir to new server
- performe *mysql_upgrade*
- Start Percona

Is there something I have to consider?

Or maybe it will be better to configure Percona as a Slave, wait until it is fully synced and make it a master? Is that possible too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the Master-Slave approach works quit nice. After the Slave was up and running, I could promote the slave to a master.